# Sending an email with tableview and pie chart in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, attachment, email

I am new to ios application Development.So pls bear me if anywhere i m wrong.I want to send an email from my app with the attachment.Attachment contains tableview and a pie chart.I searched in google and find taking screenshots and sending mail..But i have lot of rows in my tableview.So is that any other better alternative way to send a table of data as a mail attachment? any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could create a html table out of your tableview data. HTML tables are quite easy to create with some NSString magic.
A very basic table looks like this:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>row 1, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 1, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>row 2, cell 1</td>
    <td>row 2, cell 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

the code to create such a table could look like this:

```
    NSString *tableStart = @"<table border=\"1\">\n";
    NSString *rowStart = @"  <tr>\n";
    NSString *cellStart = @"    <td>";
    NSString *cellEnd = @"</td>\n";
    NSString *rowEnd = @"  </tr>\n";
    NSString *tableEnd = @"</table>";

    NSMutableString *table = [NSMutableString string];
    [table appendString:tableStart];
    for (MyObject *object in self.dataSource) {
        [table appendString:rowStart];  // one row for each object

        [table appendString:cellStart]; // first cell for title
        [table appendString:object.title];
        [table appendString:cellEnd];

        [table appendString:cellStart]; // second cell for rating
        [table appendFormat:@"Rating %d", object.rating];
        [table appendString:cellEnd];

        [table appendString:rowEnd];
    }
    [table appendString:tableEnd];
```

this will create a very basic table. With some html knowledge you can add more fanciness.

When you have that table embed it in a html document and send the email as html.

If you want to go this way you have to learn the basics of html. There is a lot of information about this in the web. You could start with those two links.

http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/1-introduction-to-the-web-standards-cur/#toc
http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/19-html-tables/

Comment: Thank You bro...Its helped me a lot..But it brings a long coding..In my table i have 180-360 rows...So i m gonna use .csv file to send my data...Anyway thanks for your help..